# How to SUM values with same value by using WHERE IN()

Tags: mysql, query

I'm trying to sum the total of items in a cart by ID, so i was trying simply to `SUM` the values by passing IDs in the `WHERE` clause.

But if i'm using the `WHERE IN` to add the IDs the `SUM` is going to sum only **different** IDs so if i have in `WHERE` ID 104 **twice it will sum it only once**.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IMPORTO) AS TOTAL
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(PRE_PRP) AS IMPORTO
    FROM vo_plurep
    WHERE ID_PLUREP IN (12782 , 12800, 12804, 12810, 12802, 12798, 12784, 12798, 12802) 

    UNION ALL 
 
    SELECT SUM(PRE_VAR) AS IMPORTO
    FROM vo_varianti
    WHERE ID_VARIANTI IN (104 , 104, 142)
) AS TOT
```

Is there a way to force MySql to sum even the same values in `where` clause?

Comment: No, WHERE IN does not allow this, You must convert your values list into the rowset (with duplicated values) and join it to source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IN predicate will either evaluate to TRUE or FALSE (or NULL) exactly once for each row, so you won't get any multiplier effect from that. You can use a Common Table Expression (CTE, only supported in 8+) or a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE vo_plurep
( ID_PLUREP int not null
, PRE_PRP int not null
);

insert into vo_plurep (id_plurep, pre_prp) values (1,1),(2,2);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T (id_plurep int not null);

insert into T (id_plurep) values (1),(1);

SELECT SUM(PRE_PRP) AS IMPORTO
FROM vo_plurep
JOIN T
    ON T.id_plurep = vo_plurep.id_plurep


IMPORTO
2
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06e737db115771c35714656d10376627)

Answer (score 1):

Convert

```
SELECT SUM(PRE_VAR) AS IMPORTO
FROM vo_varianti
WHERE ID_VARIANTI IN (104 , 104, 142)
```

to, for example,

```
SELECT SUM(PRE_VAR) AS IMPORTO
FROM vo_varianti
JOIN (SELECT 104 ID_VARIANTI UNION ALL 
      SELECT 104 UNION ALL
      SELECT 102) criteria USING (ID_VARIANTI)
```

or use any other technique for to create a rowset (for example, transfer criteria as JSON or CSV and parse it to rowset with JSON_TABLE() function).